# precrec, Sensitivity and normalized rank of a perfect model

Tags: r, roc

I have some problem interpreting the following graphs that plot Sensitivity vs Normalized Rank of a perfect model.

```
library(precrec)
p <- rbinom(100, 1, 0.5) # same vector for predictions and observations
prc <- evalmod(scores = p, labels = p, mode="basic")

autoplot(prc, c("Specificity", "Sensitivity"))
```

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqaSq.png)

I would expect that a perfect model would generate values of Specificity = Sensitivity = 1 for all the retrieved ranked documents and thus, a line with slope 0 and intercept 1. I am clearly missing something and/or misinterpreting the x axis label. Any hint?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An explanation was provided by the creator of the package [here](https://github.com/takayasaito/precrec/issues/10#issuecomment-4769386900)